# Creating multiple directories and writing multiple files async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, fs

I need to create multiple directories and write multiple files asyncrounously. So far so good, my code works as expected but I can't make it return a status containing a value for success or fail. the function always returns 'undefined'. I know it has to do with the function returning a value before it has completed any operation, but can't figure out why.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const jimp = require('jimp');

/**
 * Creates a directory recursively
 * @param {Array} paths array of paths
 * @returns {Array} 200 for success ERROR for fail
 */
const createFolderRecursive = async (paths) => paths.map((path) => {
  fs.mkdir(path, { recursive: true }, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  });
  return 200;
});

/**
 * Makes new directory in folder images/products/{ref}
 *  saves products images and thumbnails
 * @param {Array} images Images array to be saved
 * @param {string} sku the product SKU which is going to be the path /images/products/${sku}
 * @returns {Number} if successfull returns 200 else returns 500
 */
const saveImages = async (images, sku) => {
  createFolderRecursive([
    `${__dirname}/../images/products/${sku}`,
    `${__dirname}/../images/products/thumbnails/${sku}`,
  ]).then((a) => {
    if (a.every(((val) => val === 200))) {
      return Promise.all(images.map((image, i) => {
        const base64Image = image.split(';base64,').pop();
        fs.writeFile(`${__dirname}/../images/products/${sku}/image${i}.png`,
          base64Image, { encoding: 'base64' }, (err) => {
            if (err) {
              throw err;
            }
            return 200;
          });

        jimp.read(Buffer.from(base64Image, 'base64')).then((img) => {
          img.resize(jimp.AUTO, 415);
          img.quality(50);
          img.write(`${__dirname}/../images/products/thumbnails/${sku}/image${i}.jpeg`);
          return 200;
        });
      })).then((status) => console.log(status));
    }
    return 500;
  }).catch((err) => err);
};

module.exports = saveImages;
```

The code works, all files are written successfully, but 'undefined' is returned. I need it to be 200 or 500, for a condition in another module.

thanks for the effort.

Comment: `fs.mkdir()` and `fs.writeFile()` don't return promises. There's multiple issues that need to be addressed in this code, but primarily the issue seems to be not understanding the difference between callbacks and promises.

Comment: Ok, cool. Could you describe what would you do for achieving this? Should I remove all `Promisse.all` and use only callbacks for the `fs.mkdir()` and `fs.writeFile()`. and run the jimp function inside the `fs.writeFile` callback? Thanks

Comment: or maybe wrap only the `jimp.read` in a promisse, since it returns one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't design your own error codes, just allow [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to resolve or reject naturally based on their success. And if you're writing [`async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), you should take advantage of the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) keyword instead of using [`.then(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const jimp = require('jimp');

const products = `${__dirname}/../images/products`;

const createFolderRecursive = async paths => {
  const dirPromises = paths.map(path => fs.promises.mkdir(path, { recursive: true }));
  await Promise.all(dirPromises);
};

const saveImage = async (image, index) => {
  const pngBuffer = Buffer.from(image.split(';base64,').pop(), 'base64');
  const pngPromise = fs.promises.writeFile(`${products}/${sku}/image${index}.png`, pngBuffer);
  const img = await jimp.read(pngBuffer);
  const jpgPromise = img
    .resize(jimp.AUTO, 415)
    .quality(50)
    .write(`${products}/thumbnails/${sku}/image${index}.jpeg`);

  await Promise.all([pngPromise, jpgPromise]);
};

const saveImages = async (images, sku) => {
  await createFolderRecursive([
    `${products}/${sku}`,
    `${products}/thumbnails/${sku}`
  ]);

  const imgPromises = images.map(saveImage);
  await Promise.all(imgPromises);
};

module.exports = saveImages;
```

Then you can check for errors by calling:

```js
saveImages(myImages, mySku).then(
  () => { /* success */ },
  reason => { /* error */ }
);
```

or

```js
const someAsyncFunction = async () {
  try {
    await saveImages(myImages, mySku);
    /* success */
  } catch (reason) {
    /* error */
  }
};
```